# Adobe CQ (AEM) 6.3 Did Not Load Servlet

Tags: servlets, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I had a jar from CQ 5.6 that expose several servlets. I moved the jar to new CQ 6.3 only to find out that the servlets are not ran (tested on [Servlet Resolver](http://localhost:4502/system/console/servletresolver) and it answer with `com.day.cq.commons.servlets.NonExistingDispatcherServlet` -- equals to 404).

I have do several checklist to narrow down this issue:

- The Jar is an OSGI bundle that have OSGI-INF metadata exposing its services - including the servlet. It is compiled under CQ 5.6 earlier.
- The Bundle (jar) is properly registered and CQ shows the exposed servlets as service.
- The Jar is installed under `apps` directory where it is **included in Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler** `Execution Paths`.

Is there any missing checklist to let the servlet handle the specific path defined in `sling.servlet.paths` property?

Sorry for the noob question. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Added the rough code -- i don't think you will be interested on what happens in `doPost`. As it is unrelated with registering servlet to AEM 6.3.

```
  package com.test.something;

  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.io.*;

  import javax.jcr.*;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;

  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.text.*;


  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.User;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.*;

  import java.rmi.ServerException;
  import java.security.Principal;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.principal.PrincipalManager;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.AuthorizableExistsException;

  import java.security.*;
  import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
  import javax.crypto.Mac;
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;

  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
  import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
  import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
  import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
  import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;

  @Component(immediate = true)
  @Service
  @Properties({
   @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST"),
   @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = { "/content/test" }),
   @Property(name = "service.description", value = "Test Servlet")
  })
  public class TestServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

     @Reference
     private SlingRepository repository;
     protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SSOLogger");

     @Override
     protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServerException, IOException {
        try {
         this.doPost(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
         //do some logging
        }
     }

     @Override
     protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
      SlingHttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
         //do something
        } catch (RepositoryException ex) {
         //do some logging
        }
     }
  }
```

And yes, this servlet is registered in [OSGi Components](http://localhost:4502/system/console/components/). It states the properties correctly.

**EDIT**: Narrowing down the culprit it seems

```
@Reference
private SlingRepository repository;
```

does not seems to be loaded properly.. weird. It caused the component to be in *Satisfied* state instead of *Active*.

**EDIT**: Checking the OSGi Services in CQ, noticed that `org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository` in CQ 5.6 was provided by `com.day.crx.sling.server` while in CQ 6.3 it is provided by `com.adobe.granite.repository`. Not sure if it is the cause or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing a bit and checking the logs. Apparently the issue lies on the maven scr plugin that did not generate the necessary binding (bind and unbind in `@Reference`) methods. Basically, i need to strictly define the method such as:

```
  public class TestServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
     @Reference(bind = "bindRepository", unbind = "unbindRepository")
     private SlingRepository repository;

     protected void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
     }

     protected void unbindRepository(SlingRepository repository){
        if(this.repository == repository){
           this.repository = null;
        }
     }
  }
```

There are several item we need to check if the Service is stuck in **Satisfied** state:

- **Configuration**, is every configuration field is configured?
- **Other services** that it depends to, are they already active or also in **Satisfied** state?
- Have you **whitelisted** the service ? -- if you are using `slingRepository.loginAdministrative(null)`.
- Any **exception** happen when it was **activated** (denoted by `@Activate`)?

I know the checklist are incomplete, i am also still learning this OSGi thingy. It is interesting though a bit unclear (no documentation for dummies).

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are inherently OSGI components, thus you should be able to see your servlet in OSGI component web console: `/system/console/components`

your servlet might be registered but disabled for some reason, or it might not be registered due to issues with how you wrote it.

**Please provide your servlet code so we can help further**

Comment: sorry, forgot to add it earlier.